# Java: Add Background image to frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, imageicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java swing background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227423/java-swing-background-image)
>   [drawing your own buffered image on frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163925/drawing-your-own-buffered-image-on-frame)

I am trying to add a back ground image to my frame, but nothing that I have done works.

I designed a slot machine consisting of several panels added to the container. Now, I am trying to add a nice background to the frame.

I tried using the paint method. But, since I am already using the paint method to paint the reel images, it is not working on the background.

I also tried adding a JLabel, but when I do it overwrites everything or get overwritten depending on how I call it. Following is my code; any help will be much appreciated:

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class SlotMachine extends JFrame {

    private Container c = getContentPane();

    private ImageIcon handleIcon = new ImageIcon("starWars/slot-handle.png");
    private ImageIcon quitIcon = new ImageIcon("starWars/quit2.jpg");
    private ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon("starWars/logo3.jpg");
    private ImageIcon BG = new ImageIcon("space.jpg");
    private JButton spin = new JButton("Spin", handleIcon);
    private JButton quit = new JButton("Quit", quitIcon);
    private JLabel logo = new JLabel(logoIcon);
    private JLabel bankTotal = new JLabel("Empire Total");
    private JLabel bankLabel = new JLabel("$1000.00");
    private JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel("$1000.00");
    private JLabel playerTotal = new JLabel("Rebellion Total");
    private Font newFont = new Font("DialogInput",Font.ITALIC, 25);
    private JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel moneyPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 5, 5));
    private JPanel imagePanel;
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel bankPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    private JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    private SlotMachine.ReelPanel reel1 = new SlotMachine.ReelPanel();
    private SlotMachine.ReelPanel reel2 = new SlotMachine.ReelPanel();
    private SlotMachine.ReelPanel reel3 = new SlotMachine.ReelPanel();
    private AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer.player;
    private AudioDataStream continuousMusic;
    private AudioDataStream winMusic;
    private AudioDataStream force;
    private AudioDataStream force2;
    //private AudioDataStream intro;
    private ContinuousAudioDataStream audioLoop;
    private static final int DELAY = 1000;
    private static final double FUNDS = 1000.00;
    private static final float PRICE = 1;
    private int timerCounter = 0;
    private double bank = FUNDS;
    private double playerMoney = 1000.00;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(DELAY, new SlotMachine.TimeHandler());


public SlotMachine() {

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("cantina4.wav"));
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            AudioData audioData = audioStream.getData();
            continuousMusic = new AudioDataStream(audioData);            
            audioLoop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream(audioData);

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Cheer.wav"));
            audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            audioData = audioStream.getData();
            winMusic = new AudioDataStream(audioData);

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("forceNN.wav"));
            audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            audioData = audioStream.getData();
            force = new AudioDataStream(audioData);

            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("force2NN.wav"));
            audioStream = new AudioStream(inputStream);
            audioData = audioStream.getData();
            force2 = new AudioDataStream(audioData);   


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        audioPlayer.start(force);        

        // Set the font
        spin.setFont(newFont);
        quit.setFont(newFont);
        bankLabel.setFont(newFont);
        bankTotal.setFont(newFont);
        playerLabel.setFont(newFont);
        playerTotal.setFont(newFont);

        // implements start button
        spin.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        spin.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        spin.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        spin.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        spin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 370));
        spin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                audioPlayer.stop(force);
                audioPlayer.stop(force2);
                timer.start();
                reel1.startAnimation();
                reel2.startAnimation();
                reel3.startAnimation();
                spin.setEnabled(false);
                audioPlayer.start(audioLoop);
            }
        });
        // implements quit button    
        quit.setBackground(Color.RED);
        quit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                spin.setEnabled(true);
                reel1.stopAnimation();
                reel2.stopAnimation();
                reel3.stopAnimation();
                timer.stop();
                audioPlayer.stop(continuousMusic);
                audioPlayer.stop(audioLoop);
                audioPlayer.stop(winMusic);
                timerCounter = 0;
                audioPlayer.stop(force);
                audioPlayer.start(force2);
                imagePanel.repaint(); // without this call for repaint,  if you press quit but then choose to cancel
                //  the curent image and the next image would sometimes overlap this repaint may change the images but they do not overlap.
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(SlotMachine.this,
                        "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit Option",
                        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == 0) {
                    audioPlayer.start(force2);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        // create image panel
        imagePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 15, 15));
        imagePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        imagePanel.add(reel1);
        imagePanel.add(reel2);
        imagePanel.add(reel3);

        // create a panel to hold bank values
        bankTotal.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        bankLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        bankPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        bankPanel.add(bankTotal);
        bankPanel.add(bankLabel);

        // panel to hold player values
        playerTotal.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        playerLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        playerPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        playerPanel.add(playerTotal);
        playerPanel.add(playerLabel);

        // create a panel to add bank and player panels and quit button
        //moneyPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        moneyPanel.add(bankPanel);
        moneyPanel.add(playerPanel);
        moneyPanel.add(quit);
        moneyPanel.setOpaque(false);

        // this panel adds the reel panel and spin button
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 350));
        //panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.add(imagePanel);
        panel.add(spin);
        panel.setOpaque(false);

        // create the logo panel
        logoPanel.add(logo);
        //logoPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        logoPanel.setOpaque(false);        

        mainPanel.add(logoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(moneyPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.setOpaque(false);            

        //////////////////////////////////// background ???????????????????
        /// I could just set backgroung black but i want to add a image


        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setTitle("Slot Machine");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(950, 750);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);                      

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SlotMachine();
    }

    public class ReelPanel extends JPanel {

        private final static String IMAGE_NAME = "starWars/icon";
        protected ImageIcon images[];
        private int currentImage = 0;
        private final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 150;
        private final int TOTAL_IMAGES = 12;
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private Timer animationTimer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new SlotMachine.ReelPanel.TimerHandler());
        private int index;

        public ReelPanel() {
            try {
                images = new ImageIcon[TOTAL_IMAGES];
                for (int count = 0; count < images.length; count++) {
                    images[ count] = new ImageIcon(IMAGE_NAME + (count + 1) + ".jpg");
                }

                width = images[ 1].getIconWidth();
                height = images[ 1].getIconHeight();
                currentImage = 0;
                index = 0;
                animationTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            images[ currentImage].paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);

            if (animationTimer.isRunning()) {
                currentImage = (int) (Math.random() * TOTAL_IMAGES);
            }
        }

        public void startAnimation() {

            animationTimer.start();
        }

        public void stopAnimation() {
            animationTimer.stop();
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        private class TimerHandler implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                repaint();
                index = currentImage;
            }
        }
    }

    private class TimeHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            audioPlayer.stop(winMusic);
            ++timerCounter;
            if (timerCounter == 2) {
                reel1.stopAnimation();
            } else if (timerCounter == 3) {
                reel2.stopAnimation();
            } else if (timerCounter == 4) {
                reel3.stopAnimation();
                audioPlayer.stop(continuousMusic);
                audioPlayer.stop(audioLoop);
                timerCounter = 0;
                timer.stop();
                spin.setEnabled(true);
                if (reel1.getIndex() == reel2.getIndex() && reel1.getIndex() == reel3.getIndex()) {
                    if (playerMoney > 0) {
                        playerMoney += bank;
                    } else {
                        playerMoney = bank;
                    }
                    bank = FUNDS;
                    winMusic.reset();
                    audioPlayer.start(winMusic);
                } else {
                    bank += PRICE;
                    playerMoney -= PRICE;
                }

                bankLabel.setText("$" + bank + 0);
                playerLabel.setText("$" + playerMoney + 0);
                if (playerMoney <= 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SlotMachine.this,
                            "You are out of funds. GAME IS OVER", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drawing your own buffered image on frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163925/drawing-your-own-buffered-image-on-frame) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227423/java-swing-background-image or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853921/setting-a-background-image-on-a-jframe-using-swing or ..  Please search first for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the layout of your main panel to `BorderLayout`
2. Create a `JLabel` and add it to you main panel
3. Set the image icon of the label using your background image
4. Set the layout of the label to what ever you want to use
5. Continue adding your components to the label as you normally would

An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253979/place-jlabel-on-top-of-jlabel-with-image-in/12254063#12254063)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply override `paintComponent` for your `mainPanel` and draw the background image in that method. You should choose the appropriate strategy for painting your image (stretch it, keep aspect ratio, repeat horizontally/vertically) but that should not be too hard.

Here is an example that stretches the image over the content pane.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestBackgroundImage {

    private static final String BACKHGROUND_IMAGE_URL = "http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/27/2740/AEPND00Z/affiches/blue-fiber-optic-wires-against-black-background.jpg";

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestBackgroundImage.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(new URL(BACKHGROUND_IMAGE_URL));
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(backgroundImage.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            size.width = Math.max(backgroundImage.getIconWidth(), size.width);
            size.height = Math.max(backgroundImage.getIconHeight(), size.height);
            return size;
        }

        };
        mainPanel.add(new JButton("A button"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestBackgroundImage().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I Tried you r suggestion but it did not work with my project. But thank you for help.

Comment: @rafaelzm2000 If you have tried the code above, you obviously saw that it works. So, either your children components are covering the entire frame, in which case your question does not make sense (where would the background image be visible?) or you did not set it up properly in your case. Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with your problem.

Comment: you are right the code does work but i must have done something wrong when i implemented my own code because the back ground was blank. The code is working now but i will try to use your example again to see if i can get it right. Again Thanks for the help.